# Using pretty permalinks and old structure together

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress permalinks as below :

```
http://wordpress-site.com/sample-post-title
```

I want to create a php archive page so it filters posts by custom fields .
Every post has it's own custom field named developer .
I want to filter posts when someone click on a link with this structure :

```
http://wordpress-site.com/developer.php?id=developerid
```

So how can I have these two together ?
Here's a hook I'm working on it for developer.php file :

```
    function myplugin_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // check if the user is requesting an admin page 
    // or current query is not the main query
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ){
        return;
    }
    // edit the query only when post type is 'food'
    // if it isn't, return
    if ( !is_post_type_archive( 'app' ) ){
        return;
    }
    $meta_query = array();
    // add meta_query elements
    if( !empty( get_query_var( 'developer' ) ) ){
        $meta_query[] = array( 'key' => 'developer', 'value' => get_query_var( 'developer' ), 'compare' => 'LIKE' );
    }
    if( count( $meta_query ) > 1 ){
        $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';
    }
    if( count( $meta_query ) > 0 ){
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'myplugin_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't make sense. You should keep the same url structure and just pass the parameter to the url, like

http://wordpress-site.com/developer?developer=something

Or you can use custom rewrite rules to create url like

http://wordpress-site.com/developer/something